# Unable to find class com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem.NTSystem on RDi 9.5 (64-bit) JRE 1.8

Tags: java, windows, websphere

I am able to check the supplied user is system Administrator or not on windows machine with JRE 1.6 as

```
String groups[] = (new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem()).getGroupIDs();
for (int i = 0; i < groups.length; i++)
{
    if ("S-1-5-32-544".equals(groups[i]))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Ref: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-check-if-current-user-is-admin-(windows).html

But this class **NTSystem** is not available on IBM RDi 9.5 (64-bit) JRE 1.8. 
Even the complete package is not available i.e.

> com.sun.security.auth.*

Any idea, How to do the above task in RDi 9.5 (64-bit) JRE 1.8??

Answer (score 3):

Oracle said that JDK8 is changing sun.* classes

> Some APIs in the sun.* packages have changed. These APIs are not
>   intended for use by developers. **Developers importing from sun.*
>   packages do so at their own risk.** For more details,
>   see Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

src:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html

Comment: Good info Marcin

Comment: com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem is still there for Java 17.  UnixSystem and SolarisSystem however have been removed.

Comment: @trilogy Can you provide a reference for _" UnixSystem and SolarisSystem however have been removed"_? Please visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75009659/18157) and provide this information there as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @JimGarrison I cannot confirm that comment from trilogy. According to https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/tree/master/src/jdk.security.auth/share/classes/com/sun/security/auth/module only SolarisSystem has been removed. And even the source repo for Java 20 (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk20/tree/master/src/jdk.security.auth/share/classes/com/sun/security/auth/module) still contains UnixSystem.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the required JAR (rt.jar) in your JRE and it is part of JRE.

If it is available and still not able to view the classes, then you should set the the proper run time for IBM RDi.

Comment: No, can't bundle the JRE, since its a limitation to use only RDi bundled JRE, that is available on "/IBM/SDP/jdk/rt.jar".

Answer (score 1):

Got the perfect solution of my problem by using the JNA library.

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-if-current-user-is-admin-using-jna.html