# Why UnixSystem().getUsername() is returning null ( OpenJDK 17 in Docker )

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet, java-17

Following code works on OSX

```
var hadoopInputFile  = org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.fromPath(parquetPath, new Configuration())
```

but it doesn't on Linux:

```
failure to login: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
    at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:67)
    at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule.login(UnixLoginModule.java:134)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:726)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:665)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:663)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:663)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:2065)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.createLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:3746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:3736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.fromPath(HadoopInputFile.java:38)
...
```

i found that `new com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixSystem().getUsername()` returns `null` but it shouldn't

any thoughts how to fix it or work around?

UPD
Since this is happening inside docker container
Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 AS tests
ENV WORKDIR="/application"
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}
COPY . $WORKDIR/
```

run command:

```
      docker run
        --user 0:1001
        --volume $(command -v docker):/usr/bin/docker
        --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        --volume $(pwd):/path/to/project/application
        app_tag bash -c
        "umask 002;
        mvn --settings ./.m2-settings.xml package"
```

UPD 2
i found thad `id` gives `uid=1001 gid=1001 groups=1001`
and `whoami` - `whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1001`

for now workaround is to add to Dockerfile

```
RUN groupadd -g 1001 sysadmin
RUN useradd appadmin -u 1001 -g 1001 -m -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: See the comment from @trilogy on the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45208857/18157)

Comment: It could be a problem similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527958/docker-error-getting-username-from-password-database (i.e. the uid that your container uses has no uid-to-username mapping within the container).

Comment: [Latest version](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.4/index.html) only supports Java 11 runtime

Comment: @ThomasKläger it seems it is the case, adding ```RUN groupadd -g 1001 sysadmin   
RUN useradd appadmin -u 1001 -g 1001 -m -s /bin/bash``` to Dockerfile helped

Comment: This information might be useful for others too. May I suggest that you write down your findings as your own answer and then accept it?

Answer (score 2):

adding to Dockerfile solves the issue

```
RUN groupadd -g 1001 sysadmin
RUN useradd appadmin -u 1001 -g 1001 -m -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: This answer also solved a different issue for me. creating a parquet file using hadoop's library to GCS.
When migrated from GAE to to GKE pods has the same issue. adding these line (change the pid accordingly, and using appadmin as group as well) solved the issue.

thanks you!